# Winston Logging with Mongoose Docs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, winston

I recently just switched over to Winston for logging and noticed an issue when logging mongoose docs after an exec.

Example:

```
Model.find().exec(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs) // Prints the collection fine
    winston.info(docs) // Prints a ton on mongoose stuff, related to the query
});
```

So basically how do I get winston logging to print the same way as you get from console.log? I'm guessing it must how it is being serialised before being logged by calling toJSON().

Do I have to manually call .toJSON() each time or have people done something else to make this work automatically?

Comment: I have the same problem and found no solution yet. do you solved it finally?

Comment: unfortunately no but, I will play around with some of the proposed answer below. I guess winston was never intended to for pretty object logging.

Answer (score 4):

### Warning

I think the intended use of winston is to log string messages in first place and (if needed) additional meta information. Moreover, I do not quite get why you would like to log the whole collection returned from mongo and not - let say - just `_id`s (assuming `docs` may be pretty big).

### Intro

I looked into `winston` source and here are relevant parts:

*winston/logger.js*

```
Logger.prototype.log = function (level) {
  var self = this,
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  ...

  var callback = typeof args[args.length - 1] === 'function' ? args.pop() : null,
      meta     = typeof args[args.length - 1] === 'object' ? args.pop() : {},
      msg      = util.format.apply(null, args);

  ...

}
```

Basically, single argument of type `object` is interpreted as the meta.
Console transport layer (default) is mainly defined in *winston/common.js* and here is how meta is handled:

```
 ... if (Object.keys(meta).length > 0) {
      output += ' ' + (
        options.prettyPrint
          ? ('\n' + util.inspect(meta, false, null, options.colorize))
          : exports.serialize(meta)
      );
    }
```

*serialize* method iterates (recursively) over all keys of an object to form the final string (instead of calling `.toString` or similar).

### Proposed Solutions

Both solutions force winston to interpret a single object argument not as meta but as the message string.

If you want to support different transport layers than they have to be modified.

#### Change winston source-code

Just fork the repo and make relevant changes to the source code. There is plenty of ways to accomplish it. One ugly could be:

```
 meta     = args.length === 1 ? {} :
          (typeof args[args.length - 1] === 'object' ? args.pop() : {}),
```

But much better would be to add special case in the `.serialize` method make special treatment if the object is mangoose model, very naive and incorrect:

```
 else if ('_doc' in obj && 'save' in obj){
        var result = [];
        msg += '{'
        for(var key in obj['_doc']){
            result.push (key + ':' + obj['_doc'][key]);
        }
        msg += result.join(', ');
        msg += '}';
    }
```

(Unfortunately there is a problem with this approach, as winston makes copy of the meta and all methods defined higher in prototypical chain are lost -- otherwise it would as easy as calling `obj.toJSON` and for sure it would be the most elegant and robust solution)

#### Override winston default behaviour

```
var original = winston.log;
winston.log = function(){
    if(arguments.length === 2){
        original.call(winston, arguments[0], arguments[1], {});
    }
    else {
        original.apply(winston, arguments);
    }
}
```

Explanation: `arguments[0]` defines level so `arguments[1]` is the actual object to be logged.

Comment: I will try this approach. The point was that in general, it doesn't log objects as well as the console.log Also in some cases I would like to output even if it for just debugging purpose to print out a single object from my docs collection, which I have to resort to console.log for now.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I expected that winston works as console.log.

Answer (score 3):

I've combined the ideas in the previous answers to provide a fairly robust method for logging out meta objects, which I've been running for many months in production without any issues.

The general idea is to override `transport.log` and convert the meta object to a JSON string, and back again. This ensures the meta object is preserved as an object, and hence take advantage of the winston goodies for meta objects, such as `prettyPrint`.

Here's the code for creating a new logger, with a prettyPrint option:

```
var transport = new (winston.transports.Console)({
  prettyPrint: function(meta) {
    return util.format('%j', meta);
  }
});

var originalLog = transport.log;
transport.log = function(level, msg, meta, callback) {
  if(meta) {
    if(meta instanceof Error) {
      // Errors cannot be stringified.
      meta = meta.toString();

    } else {
      // Keep meta as an object so that winston formats it
      // nicely, but ensure we don't have any weird ObjectIds
      meta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(meta));
    }
  }
  return originalLog.call(transport, level, msg, meta, callback);
};

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [transport]
});
```

You can now use the logger like so:

```
logger.debug('My Mongoose document:', doc);
```

Which will output something like:

`debug: My Mongoose document: {"_id":"56f0598b130b3cfb16d76b3d","name":"Bob"}`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to convert Mongoose model object into JSON string and pass that to winston function. For Array you may have to call function in loop.

```
winston.info(JSON.stringify(doc));
```